# Ordering of numbers in file name in FileZilla and WinSCP?

Tags: ftp, filenames, filezilla, winscp

I'm using two FTP/SFTP programs, [FileZilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XnxY.png) and [WinSCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4RAe.png), and I wonder how they sort the files in file name order.

I have 400 files with names `filename1_aa.csv` to `filename400_aa.csv`. In FileZilla, after `199` comes `19_`, and then comes `1_`.

I think it compares character by character, and `9` comes before `_`. In WinSCP, it's exactly in the order of 'numbers'.

It is more intuitive to humans, but I don't understand how this software sorts file names. Does anybody know how WinSCP sorts file names, or how I can change sort order in FileZilla? I tried in Settings, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since [version 5.6.2](https://winscp.net/tracker/425), WinSCP uses the [`StrCmpLogicalW` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) for file sorting:

> Compares two Unicode strings. Digits in the strings are considered as numerical content rather than text.

You can turn that off by unchecking [*"Use natural order numerical sorting"* option in Preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_panels).

---

In FileZilla you can achieve similar functionality by going to *Edit > Settings > Interface > File lists > Name sorting mode > Natural sort*.